# Video frame by frame Search Engine

Tags: c#, project

So here is the thing .. i have my final year project coming and i have this idea of video search engine ...

It will do these following things ... get the user query or whatever he/she wants to search and then search the video frame by frame ... and i know it might take a lot of time ...

There actually will be two steps the pre-processing stage where the algorithm will run that will put tag on videos like youtube does.. only this time the tagging will be done by the algorithm which i don't know of..

I just need an initial push to start ...

Is there any algorithm which will give the result i want ..?

PS : This will only work for video Lectures ..if there are any other ideas please do tell.. !

Comment: Are you planning on doing OCR from a text query on every frame?

Comment: Yes kind of ...what i will do is tag the video frame by frame by the text that appears on each video .. so that the student will automatically be directed to the time of interest without going through the whole video manually ..

Comment: That would be incredibly wasteful. If you're expecting text in the video, you're going to encounter thousands of frames that are nearly identical. You should first search for the transitions, where there is actually something changing in the video. Then you can group subsets of frames together, and tag them as a group, doing the OCR only once.

Comment: i know that i will encounter in future when i start working on it .. it was just a vague idea .. ?
Can you suggest any algorithms ??

Comment: [Sure.](http://www.google.com/search?q=detect+transition+in+video+algorithm)

Comment: An excellent tool for retrieving video frames is FFMPEG.  There is a C# wrapper for FFMPEG, but you can also just shell-execute the program directly.  In my experience, FFMPEG is the only way to reliably get frames from a video file.

Comment: So what you are saying is check for transitions in the video and then apply ocr on it ..using FFMPEG ... ? or is there any other way of implementating it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the problem in to it's component parts first as there will be no one solution or algrorithom to do what you want (otherwise your Sr. Project would be done for you already).

From what I can tell here are the parts that I can see.

1. Get a video stream
2. Split the video stream in to relevant chunks to process in detail. (look for more than say 30% change in a short time span (like a blackboard being erased))
3. Process the chunk in detail either passing it to the next step or splitting the chunk in to two smaller chunks. (maybe look for a smaller change over a longer time span)
4. OCR the text.
5. Detect if the previous chunk has the same text, if so, throw the current chunk out (you did too fine of splitting in step 3 or 4).
6. Store the OCR data in a database of some sort with the time index of the text.
7. Build a program to query that database for student use.

Each of those steps will have sub steps to them that you can use the same technique of divide and conquer to figure out how to do that step.

If you need any help doing one of those singular steps let us know in a new question (one topic per question please).